# Cython Compiling Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, cython

```
C:\Users\AliAbbas\Google Drive\Work\J.E.S.S\Cython\Code>python setup.py build_ex
t -i --compile=mingw32 -DMS_WIN64
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup(ext_modules = cythonize("HelloWorld.pyx"))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_comma
nds
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_comma
nd
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 308,
 in run
    force=self.force)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new
_compiler
    return klass(None, dry_run, force)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 282, i
n __init__
    CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 157, i
n __init__
    self.dll_libraries = get_msvcr()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 86, in
 get_msvcr
    raise ValueError("Unknown MS Compiler version %s " % msc_ver)
ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1900
```

I've been trying to compile this code for a few days now, and after several errors, I got here and I have no idea what to do next. I've already installed MingW32 and don't know what to do next

I'm following O'Reilly's book on cython, using windows 8.1, and have been trying on Python 3.6.1 and 3.5.1

Comment: This kind of thing is always hard to set up or diagnose remotely - often the best solution is to use a Python distribution that has all the libraries and a compiler set up. I've used WinPython myself (although I think 3.6 might not work with mingw on any distribution). If you don't want to do that then you need to provide further details on what exactly you've installed and where (as much information as you can). Also, I'm not sure whether Mingw32 and 64 bit Python can work together - have you checked?

Comment: @DavidW
I tried it with a 64-bit MinGW distribution (mingw-w64, I think that's close), switched to WinPy 3.5.3 from Python 3.6 and after writing this:

`C:\Users\AliAbbas\Google Drive\Work\J.E.S.S\Cython\Code>python setup.py build_ex
t -i --compiler=mingw32 -DMS_WIN64`

I got the same error that I got on the first try when I was using Cython for the first time: 

`TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= str()`

I don't know what else to do now

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: The one further thing I'd try is to do it without the `--compiler=mingw32` bit of the line (it should hopefully pick the compiler automatically). Other than that I don't know - sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You're using Python 3.5 did you make sure you're using the compiler that matches what Python was built with?  A google search should find that pretty quick.  Visual Studio 2015 community is right for most Windows builds.  I see in your post you're also trying Linux which would be some GCC variant most likely.

Comment: Well, I have visual Studio 2017 installed, and it should have c++ compiler installed right? If not, then how do I check that?

Comment: @AliAbbas if you have (C)Python 3.5 for Windows then you MUST use Visual Studio 2015.  As I mentioned use Community version and it will give you a developer command prompt in your Windows drop-down menus which should load all the required VS 2015 libraries for your build.  Like `MSBuild Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2015`

Comment: You can also type: `import sys` followed by `print(sys.version)` and it should tell you the compiler for your Python you're using.